# Переменные в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Вопросы закомментированы в коде:

```
SELECT t1.name,
       # можно ли сохранить результат в переменную, что бы ниже при вычислениях не вызывать SELECT повторно?
       (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM users WHERE users.name = u1.name)                battles, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.player_type = 'A' THEN 1 END)                          count_a,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.player_type = 'B' THEN 1 END)                          count_b,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.player_type = 'C' THEN 1 END)                          count_c,
       # И возможно ли сохранить результат выполнения COUNT?
       # что бы к примеру ниже написать battles / count_type_a
       (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM users WHERE users.name = u1.name) /
       COUNT(CASE WHEN u2.player_type = 'A' THEN 1 END)                          avgA
FROM players t1
LEFT JOIN players t2
  ON  t1.battle_id = t2.battle_id
  AND t1.player_key = t2.killer_player_key
GROUP BY t1.name;
```

Comment: `@count := (select ... )` и да, далее по тексту в пределах списка выборки вы можете использовать `@count / count(case )...`. Хотя конечно и второй count можете в другую переменную сохранить для удобства

Comment: @Mike получаю неверные результаты при таком подходе. Как смогу дополню вопрос неудачными попытками.

Comment: Это видимо из за group by, переменные наверно раньше применяются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо переменных в SQL принято оборачивать выборку внешним запросом и использовать алиасы:

```
SELECT name, battles, count_a, count_b, count_c,
       battles / count_a avgA
  FROM (
        SELECT t1.name,
               (SELECT COUNT(name) FROM users WHERE users.name = u1.name) battles, 
               COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.player_type = 'A' THEN 1 END) count_a,
               COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.player_type = 'B' THEN 1 END) count_b,
               COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.player_type = 'C' THEN 1 END) count_c
     FROM players t1
     LEFT JOIN players t2
       ON  t1.battle_id = t2.battle_id
      AND t1.player_key = t2.killer_player_key
    GROUP BY t1.name
  ) X
```

Comment: Отличный ответ. Можно было бы ещё заменить - "принято использовать другой подход" на примерно такое - "принято использовать алиасы из подзапроса". На ваше усмотрение, т.к. у вас точность формулировок получше, чем у меня.

Comment: Можете посоветовать литературу по БД. Хочу повысить знания по БД. Сейчас мои знания только на уровне CRUD операций. "Алиасы из подзапроса" - первый раз слышу, пойду гуглить.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ. Совсем не то что я спрашивал, но благодаря ответу понял что я совсем не понимаю SQL. И написал достаточно сложных и "корявых" запросов. Переосмыслив я переписал пару запросов и все стало проще и веселее. Если я верно понял, то SELECT внутри формирует новую таблицу, из которой внешним SELECT я делаю необходимые арифметические операции. Вопросы оптимизации и производительности оставлю на потом :) сейчас интересуюсь только в образовательных целях.

Comment: @Евгений Да, это как таблица. Но и с производительностью на этом проблем не бывает. Эта "таблица", она виртуальная, она не пытается нигде сохраняться. В сложных ситуациях иной раз приходится 3-4  уровня так вкладывать и оптимизатор отлично разбирается со всем этим